# Incompatible key type List<String> for Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: apex, list, compile-error

**Error**

> Error: Compile Error: Incompatible key type List for Map> at line 52 column 24

**Code**

```
public class contactcontoller{
    public list<contact> {get;set;}
    public contact con{get;set;}
    public contactcontoller(ApexPages.standardcontroller sc){
       con = new contact();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to add a List<String> in your recordMap which is a Map with strings as keys : recordMAP.put( SIT, obj );

Answer (score 3):

`siteSetFromCsv` is just a `Set <String>`, you are trying iterate over it like its a list of lists on line 52 `for( List <String> SIT  : siteSetFromCsv )`. In the future it might be helpful to indicate line numbers if the error is related to a specific one BTW.